# SQL Server : date subtract

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, stored-procedures, where-clause

I am trying to do a stored procedure where I will get all people that have there `StartDate` value strictly equal to today's day -7 days. So I can activate them 7 days before getting to there start date.

For example I have a user 'test1' that his `StartDate` ='2020-12-08 00:00:00.000'

So my query should get only this record cause his

`StartDate` = Today's date - 7 days.

`StartDate` is my record that I check

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ActivePersonXdaysBeforeStartDate
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT * 
    FROM Person 
    WHERE Active = 0
      AND DATEADD (DAY, -7, StartDate) = GETDATE()
END
```

But this is not working any tips on how to do that? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you want:

```
select * 
from person 
where active = 0 and startdate < dateadd (day, -7, convert(date, getdate()))
```

This brings all rows that are not active and whose `startdate` is (strictly) less than 7 days before today (not including the time component of today).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and answer it does work perfectly but I am not getting the result I am expecting

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and answer it does work perfectly but I am not getting the result I am expecting I have a Record that is StartDate is  2020-12-8 00:00:00.000 and when i execute the query it should apear but i doesn't. I am trying to get all people that today +7 days . So i will be getting only people that have exaclty today+ 7 day more then that i don't need them. Sorry for my mistak

Comment: then try startdate <= dateadd (day, 7, convert(date, getdate()))